# Admob Banner does not appear in my mainActivity

Tags: android, admob

I follow the official documentation:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

But I can't find a mistake in my code. I tried to change

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

For the test AdRequest but it's still not working.

This is my source code:

https://github.com/sssolammm/HelloWordTestBanner

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-5676983055182772~7282283135");

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_View);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdFailedToLoad");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
            // covers the screen.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdLeftApplication");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
            // to the app after tapping on an ad.
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/** Called when leaving the activity */
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

/** Called when returning to the activity */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.resume();
    }
}

/** Called before the activity is destroyed */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

**Xml layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_View"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Set the adListener before calling loadAd and check if "onAdFailedToLoad" apears in the log.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your test device id to builder.
If it works with test id, it will be working on production.

`AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
.addTestDevice("your id")  // Put here your test device id 
.build();`

For test device id, go in Logcat after run app, put in Verbose put in the search field AdRequest, so the id device shows down.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes ad is not shown...then i uninstall my application and change build variants from debug to release.

After then i install my app again...banner ad will be shown successfully.

even if banner ad is not showing..then i check the log info...and get the test device id..add this test device id to AdRequest object...and i am sure banner ad will be shown.

adRequest.addTestDevice("your id")